# Задачка про поезд. Нужен алгоритм. Важна скорость

Tags: c, алгоритм

Задача: Вы просыпаетесь в вагоне поезда. Все вагоны поезда соединены в кольцо. То есть из последнего вагона вы попадаете в первый. В каждом вагоне есть выключатель и лампочка. Изначально лампочки случайным образом включены или выключены. Нужно двигаясь по вагонам и используя выключатели определить количество вагонов в поезде.

Плохое решение: допустим мы выключаем свет в вагоне, в котором мы проснулись, и начинаем движение вперёд. Как только встречаем первый вагон с выключенным светом, делаем предположение, что это исходный вагон. Включаем в нем и свет и движемся обратно столько вагонов, сколько мы прошли вперёд. Если оказывается, что там свет теперь включён, значит мы нашли количество вагонов. Если нет, то начинаем все сначала.

При худшем стечении обстоятельств, мы имеем *О(n<sup>2</sup>+n)* шагов или просто *О(n<sup>2</sup>)*. В наилучшем случае просто *О(2n)*.

Вопрос: А можно быстрее?

Comment: Решение за O(n): идем по вагонам и выкручиваем лампочки.

Comment: @Yaant задачка чисто математическая. Не из серии, а мышка была на велосипеде, она быстрее кошки)

Comment: Это старая, классическая олимпиадная задача. Вам должно доставить удовольствие решить её самостоятельно.

Comment: за O(n) - выставить выключатель в среднее положение (да, оно не стабильное, но все же, обычно можно). Решение за O(1) - найти проводника/того, кто это затеял и спросить.

Comment: `найти проводника/того, кто это затеял` это может быть `O(inf)`

Answer (score 5):

Ну, попробовать так - как у вас - идти до первого включенного (пусть M), вернуться.

Если не он - идти удвоенное количество вагонов (2M), везде выключая - если потом вернемся, и наш выключен - уже знаем, что меньше 2M, так что включаем свет и идем по кругу наши N вагонов - до первого включенного.

Если опять не нашли - опять удваиваем, идем 4M вагонов. И так далее, пока не найдем нужное значение.

Если брать с M=1, то получим 2 + 4 + 8 + ... + 2^K проходов, где 2^k - первое, большее N. Насколько понимаю, мы имеем в результате O(N).

Comment: Получается 2*(1+2+4+8+...+N). Правильно я понимаю что то, что в скобках равно 2N? Итого у нас решается за 4N?

Comment: Я бы поостерегся давать точное значение :), потому что варианты могут быть разные, не обязательно число вагонов является степенью двойки. Но в любом случае O(N).

Comment: Я рассматриваю самый неблагоприятный случай. А что  если у нас будет в руках скажем какая-нибудь дощечка (память) куда мы могли бы что-то записывать и делали бы следующим образом. В первом вагоне выключаем свет и идём вперёд, выключая везде свет, до первого вагона с выключенным светом. Строим гипотезу, что это наш первый вагон, но, возвращаться не спешим, а пойдём дальше вперёд. Через такое же количество вагонов там должен быть выключен свет. То есть мы сделали два круга. И вот сейчас идём назад проверять.

Comment: Ну или каким то другим образом. То есть будем, не спешить бегать туда сюда. Может быть мы тогда проиграли бы в самом благоприятном случае, но выиграли бы скажем в среднем и самом неблагоприятном случае.

Comment: @DmitriiDunaev Ну напишите программку и смоделируйте, что получится - может быть интересное исследование!

Answer (score 0):

Проснулись и пошли. Если не ошибаюсь в условии нет ограничений на использование карандаша и бумаги. Ничего не включаем и не выключаем. Фиксируем тёмные вагоны '0' светлые '1'. Через 10 вагонов останавливаемся берём за матрицу последовательность первых трёх вагонов. Допустим (0,1,0) Ищем в "отработанных" вагонах идентичную последовательность начиная со 2 вагона. При нахождении совпадения увеличиваем матрицу +1 вагон, сравниваем "четвёрку вагонов" если опять совпадение опять +1 вагон к матрице снова сравниваем уже "пятёрку". При первом же несовпадении бросаем это дело и двигаемся дальше. Набираем ещё десяток вагонов. Снова проводим сравнение с постепенным увеличением матрицы. Рано или поздно круг замыкается и мы находим "первый" вагон. Можно вообще всё упростить до смешного. Упорядочить включённые и выключенные лампочки таким образом чтобы они строго следовали друг за другом 0 1 0 1 0 1 и продолжать движение до тех пор пока окончательно не станет ясно что идёт движение по кругу. Получится нечто вроде сортировки. После этого включая выключенные начать подсчитывать общее количество.

Comment: Ну и в итоге сложность O(n²) у вас получается, что не лучше чем у автора

Comment: Поясните пожалуйста почему у вас так получилось если автор постоянно должен возвращаться назад и проверять тот ли это вагон в то время как в моём варианте я двигаюсь только в одном направлении не делая лишних шагов?

Comment: Единственное что мне надо делать это постоянно сравнивать последовательность. Указанное мной число вагонов = 10 это чистая условность. Вагонов может быть на много меньше.

Comment: Ну у вас по сути 2 вложенных цикла, 2 окна же, большое и маленькое. Первый цикл перебирает размеры большого окна, второй — малого внутри большого. Отсюда и O(n²)

Comment: Определяя эффективность я опираюсь на количество шагов которые физически должен сделать человек находящийся в задаче.

Comment: Сложность алгоритма — число операций (например, операций сравнения). Прикиньте худший случай для 10 вагонов и для 20 вагонов (ну или для 1000 и 2000), и сравните во сколько раз увеличится число сравнений в вашем алгоритме

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127147/discussion-between--and--nop).